# how to determine whether a dll has been registered with my c++ function?

Tags: c++, dll, registration

A newbie question-

I want to write a wrapper function in windows c++ which will look into some input parameters passed and based on whether an associated dll is registered or not would respond to the application.

So basically i need to

1)register dlls with my wrapper fn
2)the wrapper should scan through the registered dlls

what is the best way to do this?? where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by register - are we talking about COM registration or your own custom registration system?

In any case, once you know what DLLs to load, use [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load the DLL into memory, and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get pointers to exported functions from the DLL. If you're doing a plugin-style thing, you'll probably want to call an initialization function in the DLL, and allow the DLL to do any setup it may need to register itself with your application.

Comment: @bdonlan- I guess my terminology reflects my inexperience in windows programming :D I meant register as to qualify a custom registration system.  I will use loadlibrary and getproc address to get the fn pointers. Thats fine. What I am not sure is how to look at the PE of .exe  given to me , get the imported dlls and check against the dlls registered with my system. Some direction would set me up. I learned that I need to map it into a SEC_IMAGE file and parse the PEs. Is that the right way to go??

Comment: Why are you looking at the .exe's imports directly?

Comment: my aim is to write a wrapper function before the exes execute.I am using api hooking to trace some code and emulate it. now i want to make it generic to work on different exe files. I want my system to take files that it can emulate while saying no to the ones whose dll i cannot hook into.

Comment: Okay, this is an entirely different (and much more difficult!) task then. You should probably open a separate question.